# What is the difference between pipe output to in-place computation?

Tags: bash, pipe

I am trying to modify my git remote repo address and I got confused over pipe (`|`).
What is the difference between the two and why the first option doesn't work?

```bsh
# Doesn't work
git remote get-url origin | sed 's/old/new/' | git remote set-url origin

# Works
git remote set-url origin $(git remote get-url origin | sed 's/old/new/')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that `git remote set-url` needs its final argument (the actual URL) on the command line, *not* as its standard input. Your first line (the one with the pipe) tries to feed the URL as standard input.

Your second line, OTOH, almost¹ correctly interpolates the URL as a command line argument (the final one) to the top-level command.

---

<sup>¹ you forgot the double quotes around the command substitution to prevent the unwanted split+glob here.</sup>